# jump() gets called but doesn't make the sprite actually jump (only 1 line in the method) - android game development

Tags: java, android, 2d, sprite

What the title says basically.

The jump worked perfectly until I decided to make my game more object-oriented by adding a **GameObject** class. The sprite should jump whenever you tap the screen **(added a print statement in jump() to verify that this method DOES get called)**. Can anyone spot the mistake?

The way I've coded the jump:

- player is constantly decelerating until he reaches the ground
- if the screen is tapped, the players ySpeed is increased by accelerationJump, then decreased slowly by g while he's in the air

**Player:**

```
public class Player extends GameObject implements InputProcessor {

private float g;
private float accelerationJump = 9f;
private boolean allowJump = true;

public Player(Sprite spr) {
    super(spr);
    setxPos(0);
    setyPos(getHeight() / 6);
    setxSpeed(5.5f);
    setySpeed(0);
    spr.setX(getxPos());
    spr.setY(getyPos());
    g = 0.2f;
    accelerationX = 0.02f;

}

public void update() {
    setySpeed(-g);

    //have the sprite constantly moving
    moveBy(getxSpeed(), getySpeed());

    //if sprite reaches end of screen, move it to the start of the screen again
    if (getxPos() > getWidth()) {
        setxPos(0);
    }

    if (getyPos() < getHeight() / 6) {
        moveTo(getSprite().getX(), getHeight() / 6);
    }
    //the player can only jump if he is on the ground. once player is on the ground, he must stop decelerating
    if (onGround()) {
        allowJump = true;
        setySpeed(0);
    }
}

public void jump() {
    System.out.println("dasdasddadsdasd");
    setySpeed(getySpeed() + accelerationJump);
}
// checks whether or not player is on the ground
public boolean onGround() {
    return (getSprite().getY() == getHeight() / 6);
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    //if (allowJump && isDragged == false) {
    //System.out.println("dsdasdasd");
    if(allowJump){
        allowJump = false;
        jump();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    /*if (isDragged == false) {
        isDragged = true;
    }*/
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}
```

}

**GameObject**
    public abstract class GameObject {

```
private Sprite spr;
private float xSpeed;
private float ySpeed;

public GameObject(Sprite spr) {
    this.spr=spr;
}

public void moveTo(float xPos2, float yPos2) {
    setxPos(xPos2);
    setyPos(yPos2);
}

public void moveBy(float dx, float dy) {
    spr.setY(spr.getY() + dy);
    spr.setX(spr.getX() + dx);
}

public float getxPos() {
    return spr.getX();
}

public float getyPos() {
    return spr.getY();
}

public void setxPos(float xPos2) {
    spr.setX(xPos2);
}

public void setyPos(float yPos) {
    spr.setY(yPos);
}

public float getxSpeed() {
    return xSpeed;
}

public float getySpeed() {
    return ySpeed;
}

public void setxSpeed(float xSpeed2) {
    xSpeed = xSpeed2;
}

public void setySpeed(float ySpeed2) {
    ySpeed = ySpeed2;
}
public int getWidth() {
    return Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
}
public int getHeight() {
    return Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
}
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    spr.draw(batch);
}

public Sprite getSprite() {
    return spr;
}
```

}

Any help is HIGHLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting ySpeed to -g every update()

Comment: yep. if the sprite isn't on the ground then it should have gravity g acting downwards on it. when the sprite jumps, it should accelerate in the y axis by accelerationJump while constantly being decremented by g. i know this isn't the issue because this is how the jump was implemented when it was working

Comment: However you are not decrementing the speed by g, you are setting the ySpeed to -g nomatter what. I think it should be something like: setYSpeed(getyspeed() -g);